# Odoo 9 Log in internal note in crm lead

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have a question about option in CRM > LEAD "Log an internal note", when switch on Log an internal note and send message my followers also receive this message on email. I won't that.

In module stay: "Log an internal note which will not be sent to followers, but which can be read by users accessing this document.

Note: I won't remove this user from folower list!

Any solution?

Comment: Could be an issue. Maybe you should create one at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues

Answer (score -1):

Log internal note is a functional feature that you put comment without disturbing followers  and if you want to notify all then you must send a message. Although if you want  to notify person discussion list in your notes then user must use mention feature (@ #) If you user @ (at) sign then you can alter some specific user and if you user # (hash) will give you discussion list to be notified.

If you still want to force do that then using development you can set comments (mail.message) type from `comment` to `email` by over-riding def create for `mail.message`.

Bests